# How to display Row details to a textbox on checking checkbox in a datagrid in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to select the rows from gridview to textbox on chekbox checked in the gridview. I get this code but its not working.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    int i = 0;
    List ChkedRow = new List <String>();

    for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value) == true)
        {
            ChkedRow.Add(i);
        }
    }

    if (ChkedRow.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select atleast one checkbox");
        return;
    }

    foreach (int k in ChkedRow)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: `Not working` doesn't tell us much. What *exactly* is the problem? What does it do? What doesn't it do? What errors does it throw?

Comment: Lets say we understand what you want, have you tried something like textBox1.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
 or even StringBuilder?

Comment: Can you post the gridview binding code and aspx code?

Comment: @Deepu I think he is using WinForms judging by his code.

Comment: @MohRizwan check my possible solution to your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert first the `Cell` to `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` and then get the `FormattedValue` to get the `CheckBox` value of **true** or **false**.

And so using your own code it would look probably like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

  List ChkedRow = new List <String>();

  for(int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
     DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkBox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
     if ((Boolean)chkBox.FormattedValue)
        {
         ChkedRow.Add(i);
        }
   }

  if (ChkedRow.Count == 0)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Select atleast one checkbox");
     return;
  }

  foreach (int k in ChkedRow)
  {
     textBox1.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value.ToString()+ " - ";
  }
}
```

You could also use `Multiline` for your `Textbox` but make sure that it's height is tall enough so that you could see all the values selected, like:

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
foreach (int k in ChkedRow)
  {
     textBox1.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks  for your response...i checked out the solution you provided . but there was issues which i solved in the code... and i got the output Really thanks for your solution.

Comment: @MohRizwan Glad to be of help although not the one that you want exactly. At least it leads you there. Happy coding and GOD bless.